# Is it possible to create additional pipeline steps based on a variable?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible in Azure Devops YAML pipelines to dynamically create additional steps based on some variable data (without creating our own plugin)

The thing is I see that I want to iterate through several directories, but I don't want to just lump it all in a single step since it makes it harder to scan through to find an error.

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update for this issue? If you've got the final answer of this issue, you can consider adding that as [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). It just a reminder :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible in Azure Devops YAML pipelines to dynamically create
>   additional steps based on some variable data (without creating our own
>   plugin)

No, Yaml pipelines(azure-pipeline.yml) are under Version Control. So what you want (for your original title) is to dynamically commit changes to the `azure-pipeline.yml` file when executing the pipeline. That's not a recommended workflow.

1.Instead you can consider using [Azure Devops Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to dynamically enable/disable the additional steps.

- [Use a template parameter as part of a condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-template-parameter-as-part-of-a-condition)
- [Use the output variable from a job in a condition in a subsequent job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-the-output-variable-from-a-job-in-a-condition-in-a-subsequent-job)
- Or Use some [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml):

  ```
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
  ```

2.If you're not using Conditions, you can check [conditional template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#parameters-to-select-a-template-at-runtime) as **Simon** suggests above.

Also, both #1 and #2 can work with new feature [runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script).

3.However, if the dynamic variable you mean comes from the result of `components = result of ls -1 $(Pipeline.Workspace)/components` command, above tips won't work for this situation. For this you can try something like this:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Write your PowerShell commands here.
      # some logic to run `components = result of ls -1 $(Pipeline.Workspace)/components` and determine whether to set the WhetherToRun=true.

      'Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=WhetherToRun]True"'

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      echo Hello world
  condition: eq(variables['WhetherToRun'], 'True')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to include steps conditionally with an [if statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#parameters-to-select-a-template-at-runtime).

I think the example of [extending a template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#extend-from-a-template) on the same page will give you a good indication of how to iterate through a list parameter and create / run a step based on each value.

Comment: per my op, I want to iterate through several directories, so I am looking for a loop rather than an if()

Comment: does the "each" keyword in the 2nd link cover this?

Comment: I think it might, except the parameter list example being passed in is still hard coded in the script (on the extends example) rather than dynamically built using something like `components = result of ls -1 $(Pipeline.Workspace)/components`

It is a good starting point though, so I will try to see how far I can take it.

Comment: just looking further it does not appear to be possible because there's no equivalent of "split" in the expression functions, so we can only deal with "strings" not lists.